# how to create a dynamic table from sobject and fieldAPIname in aura:iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components

### In my Component I have

```
<aura:attribute name="searchResult" type="List" />
<aura:attribute name="fieldNames" type="List" />
```

I want to build a table with above info ????

### In my JS I have

```
action.setCallback(this, function(response){
 var state = response.getState();
if(state === 'SUCCESS'){
    var retResponse = response.getReturnValue();
    var retRecords = retResponse.sObjectrecords; 
    var fieldsToShow = retResponse.fieldsToShow;
    var fields = fieldsToShow.split(',');
   component.set("v.searchResult", retRecords);
     component.set("v.fieldNames", fields);
```

Answer (score 1):

`lightning:recordEditForm` should fit you perfectly.

Here you have an example:

```
<lightning:recordEditForm recordId="003XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" objectApiName="Contact">
    <lightning:messages />
    <aura:iteration items="{!fields}" var="field">
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="{!field}" />
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

To see reference, go through this link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_recordEditForm.htm